# Can we see our last message in rooms we have not participated?

Tags: feature-request, chat

I have noticed that I cannot see my last message with the button `load to my last message` in rooms I don't or even I haven't participated just because this doesn't exist. This might be useful when a Room Owner (else RO) moves a message from one room to another.

I know that I can see all of my most recent messages in the page https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/UserId/?tab=recent, but what happens if I want to continuously want my last message?

The question was also asked [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379165), but didn't get any attention. I am posting it here because it is a better place to post [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) about [chat](/questions/tagged/chat).

*Note: As correctly pointed out by rene [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379165/#comment663944_379165), UI supports pagination, but it is not so much helpful.*

Comment: Why would/should the chat room display a message from a different room? that's illogical.